# Tools for aggregating data before writing to Elastic

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, aggregation

Can u please point me to the right tool to use for my use case? currently I have a lambda function that reads JSON files from S3 and write it to our **raw** index on elastic (some index with raw data).

I need to create a batch processing job that will read the same JSON files from S3 and will create an **hourly** aggregation(with avg,max,min) of the data and write it into our hourly index on elastic. I should be able to re run the job in case of a missing files on S3 or other unexpected failure.

What are the recommended tools **that are external to elastic** available for my use case? Solution should be relatively simple to implement and maintain. thanks!

Comment: You could also write your data 1:1 into a temporary index and then use [roll ups](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-rollup.html) to aggregate your data in real time into a rolled up index, which you can then query on

Comment: Val, I'm familiar with rollups & transforms, but I'm looking for an external tool to do it.

Comment: Then you should remove the elasticsearch tag :-)